# How to pass a function to component to handle a drag event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use `v-for` and `is` to render the components I need. So I create the component Cube.vue like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'cube',
    render: function(createElement) {
        return createElement("div",{
            props: {
                style: {
                    type: Object
                },
                dragstartHandler: {
                    type: Function
                },
                classNames: {
                    type: Array|String|Object
                }
            },
            style: this.style,
            attrs: {
                draggable: "true",
            },
            on: {
                dragstart: this.dragstartHandler
            },
            'class': this.classNames
        },[
            createElement("div",{
                class: ["resizer", "top-left"]
            }),
            createElement("div",{
                class: ["resizer", "top-right"]
            }),
            createElement("div",{
                class: ["resizer", "bottom-left"]
            }),
            createElement("div",{
                class: ["resizer", "bottom-right"]
            }),
        ])
    }
}
</script>
```

And then, I use it like this

```
<component
    v-for="component in components"
    :class="component.classes"
    :key="component.refValue"
    :is="component.type"
    :style="component.style"
    :dragstartHandler="component.dragstartHandler"
    :ref="component.refValue"
>
</component>
```

Everything as I expected, except the dragstartHandler. It throws an error

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "dragstart": got undefined
```

I try to console.log() the components. The result is :

```
[{…}, __ob__: Observer]
    0:
     classes: Array(2)
     dragstartHandler: ƒ ()
     refValue: "cube-0"
     style: Object
     type: "cube"
```

It really is a function. But I don't know why it go to undefined in the render. I have checked I didn't spell wrong.
I just want pass the function to the component to handle the drag event. So how does it happened and what should I do to resolve it.
The dragHandler function is these:

```
dragstartCopyHandler(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData("elementId", event.target.id);
      event.dataTransfer.setData("componentOffsetX", event.offsetX);
      event.dataTransfer.setData("componnetOffsetY", event.offsetY);
      event.dataTransfer.setData("dropEffect", "copy");
      event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
    },
dragstartMoveHandler(event) {
      console.log("move start")
      event.dataTransfer.setData("elementId", event.target.id);
      event.dataTransfer.setData("componentOffsetX", event.offsetX);
      event.dataTransfer.setData("componnetOffsetY", event.offsetY);
      event.dataTransfer.setData("dropEffect", "move");
      event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    },
```

And I pass the dragstartMoveHandler to the component.

```
this.components.push({
            refValue: `${elementId}-${this.count}`,
            type: elementId,
            style: style,
            dragstartHandler: this.dragstartMoveHandler,
            classes: ["component", elementId]
          });
```

I write the pages use js to control Dom before. And today I want to rewrite it with vue. So here might something wrong with the function, but the problem now is the function passed is undefined.

Comment: What is the dragstartHandler function? Is that something you wrote?

Comment: yes, I write two function dragstartMoveHandler and dragstartCopyHandler. And I pass the dragstartMoveHandler to the component.

Comment: I have add the function in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cube` component needs to define a prop for `dragstartHandler` so that it receives it from the parent for passing it on to the div.  The same is true of the `style` and `class` bindings, which are also not working as you expect, but you don't see an error there because those are built-in bindings which get transferred to the root element.

**Cube.vue**

```js
  render() {
     ...
  },
  props: {
    dragstartHandler: {
      type: Function,
    },
  }
```

Comment: ohhhh, thanks for your answer. It works well now. But I write the props in render is useless? I have seen the https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth document.  So what's the use of props in the data object. The document just say component props.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped.  The div is not a component, so it doesn't have props, it is just taking on attribute bindings as the root element.  If it was a `CubeSide` component that received data props instead of `div`, then it would be clear.